# How to disable RIL on Android?

Tags: cellular-radio, usb-modem

As soon as I connect a USB modem to android device, system grabs ttyACM0 and ttyACM1 in an attempt to open connection. As a result, the ports are blocked and can not be opened by other services. How, if possible, can I disable RIL on android to avoid having it block ttyACM0 and ttyACM1 as soon as modem is plugged in? Is it doable without having to rebuild Android?

I have tried making following changes in init.rc, as well as deleting ril-deamon service entry.

```
setprop ro.radio.noril yes
setprop hw.nophone true
```

Comment: Build your custom ROM.

Answer (score 3):

The consequences of disabling the RIL daemon (**rild**) is hardware dependent. Because RIL is getting more and more involved in all aspects of Radio related items, including WiFi. The easiest way to stop RIL is by killing *rild*. But you need to have a rooted device to do this. Open a command shell and get root prompt (**#**).

```
# kill -9 `pidof rild`
```

You can then check the current status with:

```
# getprop |grep init.svc.ril
...
[init.svc.ril-daemon]: [stopped]
[init.svc.ril-qmi]: [stopped]
```

To restart *rild* you have to point it to the right device and library files. You can find what these are with:

```
# getprop | grep rild.lib
...
[rild.libargs]: [-d /dev/smd0]
[rild.libpath]: [/system/lib/libril-qc-qmi-1.so]
```

Then restart with*:

```
# rild -l /system/lib/libril-qc-qmi-1.so -- -d /dev/smd0
```

<sub>* **PS.** I haven't actually tried this line, so feel free to edit this post. It's possible you also need to supply the correct *SE* context to *SU* as well...</sub>

Comment: There doesnt appear to be any process named rild running. This is android 7.1.1.

Comment: My original post was from 2014, so surely today, the more common name may be something else `ril*`, like `ril-daemon` as suggested below.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. how to stop rild

note: tested on android 4.4

### try1

```
kill -9 `pidof rild`
```

it'll auto start a new rild

### try2

```
stop service rild
```

not work for me.

### try3

```
stop ril-daemon
```

this worked, found it from `/etc/init.rc`:

```
on property:ril.reset.rild=1
    stop ril-daemon
    start ril-daemon
    setprop ril.reset.rild 0
```

//so `setprop ril.reset.rild 1` may restart rild too.

### about service name

```
service ril-daemon /system/bin/rild ...
```

found such line in `init.rc`, maybe this define the service name referred in `try3`

## 2. answer the question

maybe you can imitate config in `try3`, add this config line.

```
on property:ro.radio.noril=yes
    stop ril-daemon
```

Answer (score 1):

Killing the daemon is not the correct way although it would kill the service but you won't be able to access it again. 
Type `stop service rild` in `adb shell` and it would work again for other services properly. You can check by typing `ps` if rild process is there or not. Just worked on this a few days back.